# How to bypass CAPTCHA when using Chrome's Print-to-PDF?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, pdf, pdf-generation, captcha

I am trying to automate saving a list of webpages as PDFs. To do this, I am using this answer from StackOverflow (by Rahul_Dange), where it uses Chrome's Print-to-PDF from the command prompt (in Windows 10).

The script runs fine. However, when using command prompt to do this, a lot of the websites are asking me to verify that I'm a human. So this script will simply save this "verify you're a human" page on the PDF file, instead of the actual website.

Does anyone know what a solution to this is? I've searched online and on here, but I can't find any other questions about this.